# jquery document height reported incorrectly by IE (on XP) first time

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having a "first time" problem with IE, which reports a different value for $(document).height(); when the page first loads versus subsequent queries. The difference is 17 pixels regardless of the opening size of the window -- on document ready, the height reported is 17 pixels larger than is subsequently reported. I wonder if this is an artifact of some aspect of my page (some margins or paddings somewhere), but so far can't account for 17 pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With seeing the page: Maybe after "document ready" something is happening like other DOM manipulation, or simply images finish loading whose size require a re-flow.

Comment: Yes, this is what was happening - after "document ready" there was some DOM manipulation, and the layout was different on IE than on other browsers (the DOM manipulation caused a div overflow on IE which presented a horizontal scroller, which caused the doc height to increase).